# How to get UUID with Python?

Tags: macos, python, uuid

System Report will display the system's Hardware UUID in the format 01234567-89ab-cdef-0123-456789abcdef.

Using the shell we can retrieve the same UUID:

`ioreg -rd1 -c IOPlatformExpertDevice | grep -E '(UUID)'`

Is it possible to get this UUID in Python without resorting to executing a shell command?

Comment: Programming questions are off-topic here. Try StackOverflow instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: not really.

Long answer: sort of, but it's probably more trouble than it's worth, unless you really can't used the shell command for some reason. OS X doesn't really expose much system configuration to Python. Most scriptable interfaces to configure OS X are shell-based or AppleScript-based (and of course the various Objective-C APIs).

Getting the UUID is possible in AppleScript:

```
tell application "System Information"
    set profile to system profile
    quit
end tell

set delim to AppleScript's text item delimiters
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to "Hardware UUID: "
set uuid to paragraph 1 of text item 2 of profile
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to delim
uuid
```

But as you can see, it's a bit convoluted (and is much slower than the `ioreg` method, as it has to process the entire system profile).

There is a way to bridge AppleScript to Python, known as [Appscript](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/py-appscript/index.html), but it's [no longer developed](http://appscript.sourceforge.net/status.html), and not recommended for new projects. However, if you're really determined, you could convert the above AppleScript into Python using Appscript. But to be honest, it seems like a lot of trouble to get a worse result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm able to do it, but I use pyobjc as seen here:

https://gist.github.com/pudquick/c7dd1262bd81a32663f0

```
import objc
from Foundation import NSBundle

IOKit_bundle = NSBundle.bundleWithIdentifier_('com.apple.framework.IOKit')

functions = [("IOServiceGetMatchingService", b"II@"),
             ("IOServiceMatching", b"@*"),
             ("IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty", b"@I@@I"),
            ]

objc.loadBundleFunctions(IOKit_bundle, globals(), functions)

def io_key(keyname):
    return IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(IOServiceGetMatchingService(0, IOServiceMatching("IOPlatformExpertDevice".encode("utf-8"))), keyname, None, 0)

def get_hardware_uuid():
    return io_key("IOPlatformUUID".encode("utf-8"))
```

If your target for usage is the macOS system python, fortunately Apple already included pyobjc with every recent macOS release.